# AS3 logging incorrect amount of bytes

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, arrays

I am an intern trying to fix a problem with an XMLsocket outputing the wrong byte size, stored in a byte array, for the file. 
Anyone know why a XMLsocket would be output the wrong file size/byte size for a file?

Comment: Hi Megan and welcome to the site. Can you please post some code of your usage of XMLSocket? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you mean? Do you mean that data sent from Flash via the `XMLSocket` is an unexpected size when it reaches the other side? Or do you mean that the incoming data from the `XMLSocket` (received in a `DataEvent`) is not the size you expected? Where does the `ByteArray` come into play?

One thing to note: Flash expects the XMLSocket to send and receive XML which is terminated with a zero (0) byte. Could this be what's throwing you off?